# How to update a all rows from a table with data from a different table's rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, row

I'm trying to update all rows (only 3 columns I have to update) from a table that have an equal value on another table...

Here are my tables...

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[prods](
    [IdProducto] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IdGrupo] [int] NULL,
    [IdCategoria] [int] NULL,
    [IdAlmacen] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Codigo] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Nombre] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Descripcion] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Cantidad] [int] NULL,
    [Imagen] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [StockMin] [int] NULL,
    [StockMax] [int] NULL,
    [Ancho] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Alto] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Largo] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Peso] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Volumen] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Color] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Material] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Presentacion] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [bitPrecioVentaUnico] [int] NULL,
    [PrecioCompra] [money] NULL,
    [DescuentoCompra] [float] NULL,
    [PrecioVenta] [money] NULL,
    [DescuentoVenta] [float] NULL,
    [Estado] [varchar](20) NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[prodnuevos](
    [Codigo] [int] NULL,
    [itemid] [int] NULL,
    [Item] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Categoria] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Cantidad] [int] NULL,
    [Minima] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Costo] [money] NULL,
    [Valor] [money] NULL,
    [peso] [float] NULL,
    [unidades] [float] NULL
)
```

What I want to do is the following..

```
Update prods 
Set prods.PrecioCompra = prodnuevos.Costo, 
prods.PrecioVenta = prodnuevos.Costo, 
prods.Cantidad = prodnuevos.Cantidad 
WHERE prods.Nombre = prodnuevos.Item;
```

(Update PrecioCompra, PrecioVenta and Cantidad in prods using prodnuevos' Costo and Cantidad where Nombre and Item is the same)

Obviosly the query above does not work, but I just wanted to explain my problem.
I have tried various combinations of queries with success at all. (Despite having to update 3 columns, I don't mind if I have to use 3 different queries)

I have tried things like

```
    UPDATE       prods c
    SET          c.PrecioCompra =
      (SELECT        a.Costo
      FROM            prodnuevos AS a INNER JOIN
         prods AS z ON z.Nombre = a.Item 
WHERE        (a.Item = c.Nombre))
```

but no result...

Am I doing something wrong?? or it's a totally different query??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Update prods Set 
prods.PrecioCompra = prodnuevos.Costo,
prods.PrecioVenta = prodnuevos.Costo, 
prods.Cantidad = prodnuevos.Cantidad
from prods inner join prodnuevos
on prods.Nombre = prodnuevos.Item
```

Answer (score 1):

You were pretty close. Try something like this:

```
UPDATE p SET p.PrecioCompra = pn.Costo, 
    p.PrecioVenta = pn.Costo, 
    p.Cantidad = pn.Cantidad
FROM prods p
INNER JOIN prodnuevos pn
ON p.Nombre = pn.Item
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update p
set
      p.PrecioCompra = pN.Costo
    , p.PrecioVenta = pN.Costo
    , p.Cantidad = pn.Cantidad 
from
    prods p
        inner join prodsnuevos pN on p.Nombre = pN.item
```

Also, can you do a select on Nombre and on item to verify that they would be the same?  It could bee that these two columns just don't have the same values in them

Answer (score 1):

```
Update 
    prods 
Set 
  PrecioCompra = prodnuevos.Costo, 
  PrecioVenta = prodnuevos.Costo, 
  Cantidad = prodnuevos.Cantidad 
FROM 
  prodnuevos
WHERE 
  prods.Nombre = prodnuevos.Item
```